# How to add a date column in Search Terms Grid Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, layout, grid, search

I need to add the `updated_at` date column in the Magento search term grid. the field is presented in the `search_query` table. I'm trying to override layout  `vendor/magento/module-search/view/adminhtml/layout/search_term_grid_block.xml` to add a new column. but failed my attempts please suggest any way for the same. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Override `search_term_grid_block.xml` and use below code in my layout folder. now it's working perfectly

> [VENDOR][MODULE]/view/adminhtml/layout/search_term_grid_block.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.catalog.search.grid.columnSet">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.catalog.search.grid.columnSet.updated_at" as="updated_at">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Updated At</argument>
                    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">updated_at</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Please find the attachment for better understanding.

[image]